# findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock completion

Tags: multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I am building an app using swift and parse. I would like to implement a "pull down" refresh. This would trigger a small animation (snapchat like) for as long as my app queries the server. To query the server I have a class with a function that executes two background blocks:

```
class serverCom: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    static var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    static var managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    static var mainUser = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    static func letsGo() {
        let userKindOfShit = [31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43]
        let searchAndDestroy = [31, 41, 42, 43]
        let searchAndAppend = [31, 32, 33]
        let notifKindOfShit = [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24]
        let theBigAQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")
        let theBigBQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")
        theBigAQuery.whereKey("nameA", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
        theBigBQuery.whereKey("nameB", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
        theBigAQuery.whereKey("seenA", equalTo: false)
        theBigBQuery.whereKey("seenB", equalTo: false)
        theBigAQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (theNoots: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if theNoots!.count == 0 {
                } else  {
                    for noot in theNoots! {
                        theBigAQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(noot.objectId!) { (thatNoot: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                thatNoot!.setValue(true, forKey: "seenA")
                                thatNoot!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                    if error  ==  nil {
                                    }
                                })
                                let typeOfNoot: Int = Int(thatNoot!.objectForKey("type") as! NSNumber)
                                let idOfTheGuy: String = thatNoot!.objectForKey("idOfB") as! String!
                                if userKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {

                                    searchAndDestroying(idOfTheGuy)
                                    if searchAndAppend.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                                        searchAndAppending(idOfTheGuy, type: typeOfNoot)
                                    }

                                } else if notifKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                                    notifProcessing(noot)


                                } else if typeOfNoot == 51 {
                                    self.mainUser.setBool(false, forKey: "hasChangedAvatar")
                                } else {
                                    print("{SECO} - Problem here, not userKindOfShit, nor notifKindOfShit")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
            }
        }

        theBigBQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (theNoots: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if theNoots!.count == 0 {
                } else {
                    for noot in theNoots! {
                        theBigBQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(noot.objectId!) { (thatNoot: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                thatNoot!.setValue(true, forKey: "seenB")
                                thatNoot!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                    if error  ==  nil {
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                })
                                let idOfTheGuy: String = thatNoot?.objectForKey("idOfA") as! String
                                var typeOfNoot: Int = Int(thatNoot!.objectForKey("type") as! NSNumber)
                                if typeOfNoot == 32 {
                                    typeOfNoot = 33
                                }
                                print(typeOfNoot)
                                if userKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                                    searchAndDestroying(idOfTheGuy)
                                    if searchAndAppend.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                                        searchAndAppending(idOfTheGuy, type: typeOfNoot)
                                    }
                                } else if notifKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                                    notifProcessing(noot)
                                } else if typeOfNoot == 51 {
                                    changeSkin(idOfTheGuy)
                                } else {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
```

I would need to know when this entire "letsGo()" function is complete: when the two queries have been executed, whether there was a new notif or not. I can divide that function into two small ones but I will still have the same problem: How to get a completion with a function executing a background block?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

Thanks to the precious help of Wain, I was able to delete the `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`function. Here is the code now:

```
static func letsGo() {
    print("{SECO} - m - main(Ignition)")
    let userKindOfShit = [31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43]
    let searchAndAppend = [31, 32, 33]
    let notifKindOfShit = [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24]
    let theBigAQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")
    let theBigBQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Notification")
    theBigAQuery.whereKey("nameA", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    theBigBQuery.whereKey("nameB", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    theBigAQuery.whereKey("seenA", equalTo: false)
    theBigBQuery.whereKey("seenB", equalTo: false)
    print("{SECO}m - still working up to here")
    theBigAQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (theNoots: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if theNoots!.count == 0 {
            } else  {
                for noot in theNoots! {
                    noot.setValue(true, forKey: "seenA")
                    let typeOfNoot: Int = Int(noot.objectForKey("type") as! NSNumber)
                    let idOfTheGuy: String = noot.objectForKey("idOfB") as! String!

                    if userKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                        searchAndDestroying(idOfTheGuy)
                        if searchAndAppend.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                            searchAndAppending(idOfTheGuy, type: typeOfNoot)
                        }
                    } else if notifKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                        notifProcessing(noot)
                    } else if typeOfNoot == 51 {
                        self.mainUser.setBool(false, forKey: "hasChangedAvatar")
                    } else {
                    }
                    noot.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error  ==  nil {
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    }

    theBigBQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (theNoots: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if theNoots!.count == 0 {
            } else {
                for noot in theNoots! {
                    noot.setValue(true, forKey: "seenB")
                    let idOfTheGuy: String = noot.objectForKey("idOfA") as! String
                    var typeOfNoot: Int = Int(noot.objectForKey("type") as! NSNumber)
                    if typeOfNoot == 32 {
                        typeOfNoot = 33
                    }
                if userKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                    searchAndDestroying(idOfTheGuy)
                    if searchAndAppend.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                        searchAndAppending(idOfTheGuy, type: typeOfNoot)
                    }
                } else if notifKindOfShit.contains(typeOfNoot) {
                    notifProcessing(noot)
                } else if typeOfNoot == 51 {
                    changeSkin(idOfTheGuy)
                } else {
                }
                noot.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error  ==  nil {
                    } else {
                    }
                })
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`?

Comment: If I don't do it this way, I cannot save the object later on.

Comment: Why? You already have the object and then you're a synchronously requesting it again.

Comment: I know this is far from efficient. But once I get the object, I need to modify a bool and then save it. If I don't query the object specifically the save function crashes...

Comment: What is the crash, it should not... You should also be collating your changed objects and saving all in one request at the end.

Comment: the problem is on the parse server. The logs tell me that I tried to save a nill object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95118/discussion-between-wain-and-quentin-malgaud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an array which holds all the objects to save and then you can save them all in 1 request using the PFObject API.

You can either chain all of the parts together so the B request starts after the A request has completed and its save is done, then call your completion handler from the B save callback.

Or, you can continue to run things in parallel and use a dispatch group / semaphores / a simple counter to know when all of the requests are complete. A nicer, but more code, way to do it would be to wrap each part in a asynchronous operation and then add them to a queue with another operation which is dependent on them all and which contains the logic for the completion handling.